# whereis does not return anything

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I want to know where my jupyter notebook executable is located. Which one is my python environment using. 
So I type

```
>whereis jupyter
```

in my terminal. But it returns nothing. When I do the same for python, it works. I definitely have jupyter installed because I can execute it using

```
>jupyter
```

.
What is happening?

Comment: Perhaps `jupyter` is an alias or shell function. Instead of the external command `whereis` which cannot see these, try the shell builtin `type`, i.e. `type jupyter`.

Comment: :o ! thanks! it tells me `jupyter is hashed` and then gives me the path. I don't really understand what that means but if you want to write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Being "hashed" is irrelevant (see `hash` in `bash`'s manual if you're really interested). If it prints a complete path then it's indeed an executable along your PATH, not an alias or function. As such, I don't know why `whereis` cannot locate it, sorry.

Comment: have you tried {which jupyter}?  works for me.

Comment: yes. `which jupyter` works. so why does whereis not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `whereis` manual:

```
 DESCRIPTION
 The whereis utility checks the standard binary directories for the specified programs, printing out
 the paths of any it finds.

 The path searched is the string returned by the sysctl(8) utility for the ``user.cs_path'' string.
```

and the output from `sysctl`:

```
sysctl user.cs_path
user.cs_path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Of course, `jupyter` is not in any of these directories.